# redirect terminal output to variable for displaying in console

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, console, subprocess

I am making a python shell that allows you to communicate with the terminal at runtime, without having to open a new window, directly through a game's console. Right now I am using the 
`self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True)` command to execute Windows command line requests. However I do not know how to catch prints such as those displayed when executing, for instance, the `driverquery` command.
Is there a simple way of redirecting these outputs as a raw string or something ?

Here's the entire class I'm using atm to execute commands through the cmd

```
import subprocess, threading, os
__id__ = 'shell'
PATH = os.getcwd()

class Command:
    def __init__(self, cmd):
        self.cmd = cmd
        self.process = None

    def run(self, timeout):
        def target():
            print('[%s]: Thread started' %__id__)
            self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True)
            self.process.communicate()
            print('[%s]: Thread finished' %__id__)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        thread.start()

        thread.join(timeout)
        if thread.is_alive():
            print('[%s]: Terminating process' %__id__)
            self.process.terminate()
            thread.join()
        #print(subprocess.check_output(PATH))
        return self.process.returncode
```

Comment: Why does your question mention [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS)?

Comment: Look at the argument `stdout=...` that can be passed to `subprocess.Popen(...)`.

Comment: @Compo I meant the DOS prompt, aka windows command line sorry

Comment: @JohanL I tried doing so by storing `self.process.communicate()` (which from what I've heard reads stdout and stderr) however this doesn't work as intended, I can't manage to get the actual 'answer' from the terminal

Comment: @PhilippeNJ, i've changed it for you, in future, please edit your own question when you're aware of an error/modification, and have acknowledged it.

Comment: So, what does the code of your attempt look like?

Comment: @Compo Thanks, will do that.

Comment: @JohanLatm I'm using this code (not mine but seems to execute commands correctly, the issue is the feedback):
`self.process = subprocess.Popen(self.cmd, shell=True); self.process.communicate()` inside a `command` class

Comment: @PhilippeNJ, please do not post your code on sites outside of the control of this one. Should that code ever be removed, deleted, or the site no longer function as it does now, future readers would be unable to see it. Once again, I've edited your question for you, to include that code. The **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61216277/edit)** link beneath your question is for you to keep the question up to date, until you receive an answer.

Comment: thank you again @Compo I'm learning, first time posting on stackoverflow

Comment: Well, in order to be able to catch `stdout` with `porcess.communicate()` you need to re-direct stdout to a pipe, using the argument `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` in your call to `subprocess.Popen(...)`. You also need to store the output from your call to, `process.communicate()`. It returns a tuple containing redirected output to `stdout` and `stderr`(_if_ they are redirected, as stated above).

Comment: thanks this solved it @JohanL